# Sql Join query- setting default value if NOT in join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a SQL query that links 2 tables to provide the data if a horse is in both the tables:

```
SELECT ProformSystem.TheDate as racedate, 
       ProformSystem.Course as course, 
       ProformSystem.TheTime as thetime, 
       ProformSystem.Horse as horse, 
       ATRSpeedRatings.rank as rank
    FROM ATRSpeedRatings 
    INNER JOIN ProformSystem ON (ATRSpeedRatings.Horse = trim(ProformSystem.Horse)) AND (ATRSpeedRatings.TheDate = ProformSystem.TheDate) order by ProformSystem.TheTime;"
```

Is it possible that if the horse in `ProformSystem.Horse` is NOT in `ATRSpeedRatings.Horse` then I just make `rank = 0` as a default value, or would I need to run a separate query?

This way I can display all horses from `ProformSystem` even if they don't have a rank in `ATRSpeedRatings`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT ps.TheDate as racedate, ps.Course as course, ps.TheTime as thetime,
       ps.Horse as horse, COALESCE(sr.rank, 0) as rank
FROM ProformSystem ps LEFT JOIN
     ATRSpeedRatings sr
     ON sr.Horse = TRIM(ps.Horse) AND sr.TheDate = ps.TheDate) 
ORDER BY ps.TheTime;
```

Note that this query uses table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Also, the `JOIN` condition `sr.Horse = trim(ps.Horse)` is highly suspect.  You should fix the data so there are no spaces in `ProformSystem`.  Fixing the data is more efficient and it will prevent problems on future queries.

Comment: brilliant, this worked perfect!  Thanks for your help